# What is the racket translation of this piece of lisp code?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sudoku

```
;; loads a board from the given file

;; it expects the board to be in the format of a single S-expression:

;; a list of nine lists, each containing 9 numbers


    (defun get-board-from-file file
      (let ((in (open file :if-does-not-exist nil)))
        (when in  (return-from get-board-from-file (read in)))
        (when (not in) (format t "~%Unable to open file ~A" file))
        )
     )
```

This is part of a soluton for a sudoku solver.

Comment: What have you tried in Racket? Is something specific in your translation not working?

Comment: I don't know Racket at all. I was trying to learn it through small translations of Lisp code, with which I have worked before.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is encouraged that you give it a crack first, show us what you come up with, and then we can help get you over specific obstacles you're having. Generally, people won't simply translate code.

Comment: The part with `(when in ...)` and `(when (not in) ...)` doesn't look like idiomatic Lisp, an `if` or a `cond` would express the intention better.

Comment: Is it a typo? the argument list of `defun` should be `(file)` instead of `file`. Also, I agree with Óscar López about the custom error handling: this looks really unnecessary. And you don't close the opened stream, which is bad. I would write `(with-open-file (in file) (let ((*read-eval* nil)) (read in)))`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it's a functional equivalent of the Lisp code in the question, but written in Racket:

```
(define (get-board-from-file file)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail:filesystem?
                   (lambda (exn) (printf "~%Unable to open file ~A" file))])
    (call-with-input-file file
      (lambda (in) (read in)))))
```

The above code handles an exception if the file doesn't exist, and makes sure that the port is closed after the file is read.